# WebAPI 2 method says 404 for one but not another method

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi 2.0 project.  I have two controllers.  One works as expected, the other gives me a 404.  The working controller:

```
    namespace SubscriptionApi.Controllers
    {
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using System.Web.Http;
        using Models.Services;

        [RoutePrefix("api/SubscriptionCheck")]
        public class SubscriptionCheckController : ApiController
        {
            public SubscriptionCheckController(IQuerySubscription queryService)
            {
                QueryService = queryService;
            }

            private IQuerySubscription QueryService { get; }

            [HttpGet] 
            [Route("Get/{email}/{productCode}")]
            public async Task<bool> Get(string email, string productCode)
            {
                return await QueryService.IsSubscribed(email, productCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

In my browser I can run the app and enter http://localhost:55816/api/SubscriptionCheck/Get/bob@place.org/PRD into a broswer.  It returns a true or false as I expect.  The failing controller is very similar.

```
    namespace SubscriptionApi.Controllers
    {
        [RoutePrefix("api/RepresentativeCheck")]
        public class RepresentativeCheckController : ApiController
        {
            public RepresentativeCheckController(IQuerySubscription queryService)
            {
                QueryService = queryService;
            }

            private IQuerySubscription QueryService { get; }

            [HttpGet]
            [Route("Get/{email}")]
            public async Task<bool> Get(string email)
            {
                return await QueryService.IsPrimaryOrAlternateRepresentative(email);
            }
        }
}
```

With the app running I enter http://localhost:55816/api/RepresentativeCheck/Get/bob@place.org and it reports "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

The global.asax is nothing strange:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

The WebApi is config'd before the MVC pages.  Using attribute routing, I wouldn't expect that the route tables have any impact, but for completeness:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.RegisterResolver();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
    }
```

I am having trouble seeing the difference between SubscriptionCheck that works fine, and RepresentativeCheck that telss me 404. Any help is appreciated.

Windows 10, VS Pro 2017 15.8.8, IIS Express

Comment: I can't see anything obvious however, in the past, I've had some luck with either [debugging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger/) or [tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api). to help determine why a given route isn't being correctly identified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems more a . (dot) issue. When you have a dot, in params passed via URI, WebAPI expects a "/" character at the end of the variable. 
To make it working you should do the call in this way

```
http://localhost:55816/api/RepresentativeCheck/Get/bob@place.org/
```

That's why your first call

```
http://localhost:55816/api/SubscriptionCheck/Get/bob@place.org/PRD
```

was working.

Try to add a . (dot) to PRD and it won't work even the SubscriptionCheck. 
Anyway in this case, when you have params which might have some special character I suggest you to use a POST verb and send a JSON to the controller.

Comment: I see.  IIS is looking for the module that handles files with the ".org" extension.

Comment: POST is not really the right thing.  The action is not posting anything to the service.  It is getting information from the service.  I have to inform IIS that it should pass fragments with dots in them to the api handler, and not look for a file handler.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a workaround that is not quite a solution, because I don't quite understand it.  RAMMFAR.  If I add a runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests attribute to my modules element, set true, it works as expected.  I discovered this because I accidentally hit the return key before I had completed the email address argument.  The API behaved as I would expect for a bad email address.  This caused me to google about '@' characters in MVC apps, and RAMMFAR was an answer.  There is some module that looks at a URL with an '@' and steals it from the pipe.  I guess.  If I want to suffer the side effects of RAMMFAR, my API now works.  I still seek to know the details.